# Can ffmpeg burn subtitles and extract frames at the same time?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, subtitles

Using [ffmpeg](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-all.1.en.html), I would like to save frames with subtitles without burning the intermediate step of burning subtitles. Is it possible?

What I do now is:

```
# first, burn the subtitles:
ffmpeg -i nosub.mp4 -vf subtitles=sub.srt withsub.mp4
# then extract frames
ffmpeg -i withsub.mp4 -vf fps=4 extracted/%05d.bmp -hide_banner
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just combine the filters with a `,`:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i nosub.mp4 -vf subtitles=sub.srt,fps=4 extracted/%05d.bmp
```

The benefit is that there will be no re-encoding of the video, so you won't lose quality.

The `-hide_banner` should come first, since it's a global option.

If you want to output both at the same time, you have to use a `filter_complex` and `split` the hard-subbed video stream into two, apply the `fps` filter to the output for bitmaps, and leave the other video stream unchanged. Via `-map` you can tell ffmpeg what to output.

```
ffmpeg -i nosub.mp4 -filter_complex "
     [0:v]subtitles=sub.srt[sub];
     [sub]split=2[sub1][sub2];
     [sub1]fps=4[out1]
     " \
    -map "[out1]" extracted/%05d.bmp \
    -map "[sub2]" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 withsub.mp4
```

I've set some video options that you might want to change if you want to adjust the quality/size of the output video.

Comment: thanks that's great! Last question, can I actually still save the video at the same time?

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you again.

Comment: In fact I am getting an error: `Could not open file : extracted`, whereas the folder exists in the current directory.

Comment: Oh that's just the `d` missing in the format I had written, there's a typo the format I had written, I corrected it on my post, you can correct it on yours if you want,

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to fix that. Good observation.